# Equivalente a scanf() en Pyton3

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, scanf, python-3.8

Tengo el siguiente problema: necesito hacer un programa que calcula el tiempo que dura un evento dadas la hora inicial y final, el problema radica en la entrada, el usuario debe escribir algo como:

> Día 5
>   08:12:23

en 'C' se puede arreglar este problema ya que tenemos el scanf() lo que funciona algo así si mal no recuerdo:

```
scanf("Día %d", día)
```

quiero realizar la misma acción o algo parecido **en Python3** que ignore la palabra "Día" y me devuelva solo el entero que esta ahí al lado.

Comment: y con dia = input() print(dia[4]) no te vale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay algo similar a `scanf` en Python, pero es relativamente simple emularlo combinando `input()` con expresiones regulares y el casting oportuno al tipo que corresponda:

```
import re

entrada  = re.search(r"\d+", input())
dia = int(entrada.group(0)) if entrada is not None else None
```

> ```
> >>> Día 5 08:12:23
> 5
> >>> Día 26 08:12:23
> 26
> >>> 30 08:12:23
> 30
> >>> foo23 08:12:23
> 23
> ```

Si quieres hacer algo similar a `scanf`, puedes restringir la expresión para que busque un entero después de `"Día "` usando un grupo de captura:

```
import re


entrada = re.search(r"Día (\d+)", input())
dia = int(entrada.group(1)) if entrada is not None else None
```

En ambos casos la variable `dia` será un entero o `None` si no encuentra el patrón. Si quieres también la hora, minutos y segundos basta con extender la expresión:

```
import re


entrada  = re.search(r"Día (\d{1,2}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})", input())

if entrada is not None:
    dia, hora, minutos, segundos = map(int, entrada.groups())
else:
    dia = hora = minutos = segundos = None
```

Hay otras aproximaciones posibles, por ejemplo usando los métodos propios de `str`, como `str.split` o `str.isdigit`, por ejemplo:

```
try:
    entrada = input().split("Día ")[1].split()[0]
    dia = int(entrada)
except (ValueError, IndexError):
    dia = None
```

Aunque son menos flexibles que regex.

Por cierto, hay algunas implementaciones por ahí de `scanf`, usando regex básicamente, una de ellas es la librería [scanf](https://pypi.org/project/scanf/) (valga la redundancia) que puedes instalar vía `pip`:

```
from scanf import scanf


dia, = scanf("Día %d") or (None, )
```

---

```
from scanf import scanf


dia, hora, minutos, segundos = scanf("Día %d %d:%d:%d") or (None, None, None, None)
```